# Подсказка для удаления вопроса написана с маленькой буквы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, удаление-вопросов

Сегодня заметил, что подсказки для удаления вопроса с маленькой буквы:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также заметил отсутствие переводов для [строки](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15766):

> Голосовать за удаление этого сообщения

но не знаю откуда она, если здесь уже переведено. Не смог найти другой строки, чтобы предложить правку.

Для поиска сообщений, которые можно удалить, можно воспользоваться [запросом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-3%20is%3Aa).

Comment: Возможно, строка помечена как удаленная в Transifex и Traducir, но на сайте еще отображается. Учитывайте, что все обновляется с некоторой задержкой. Такая строка, с маленькой буквы, в базе точно была. Когда она была удалена попробую выяснить позже.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight. спасибо большое, я просто не вижу из сайта какая где строка есть) поэтому сложно сказать то ли я поправил)

Comment: Странно, строка с маленькой буквы числиться в базе удаленной с 11 января 2021 г. Как так вышло, что мы ее видели в сентябре? Видимо, по ошибке ее на короткое время добавили заново и сразу же удалили, так что это не отразилось в Traducir. Сейчас уже все нормально, на сайте отображается строка с большой буквы.